# Problem with socket communication from docker container to the host and not the otherway around

Tags: python, docker, wsl-2

I am having some trouble with socket communication. The problem arises when the Linux container is the server and the windows host is the client. However, swapping the role works i.e. windows host is the server and the Linux container is the client.

I am running an Ubuntu container from Windows Docker Desktop, with the following cmd: `docker run -dit --expose 9090 -p 9090:9090 ubuntu:latest`. And running a simple server python script:

**Server side:**

```
import socket

def Main():

host = '172.17.0.2' #linux ip
port = 9090

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))

print("Server Started")
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    data = data.decode('utf-8')
    print("Message from: " + str(addr))
    print("From connected user: " + data)
    data = data.upper()
    print("Sending: " + data)
    s.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), addr)
c.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Main()
```

**Client side:**

```
import socket

def Main():

    host='192.168.1.6' #windows ip
    port = 9090
    
    server = ('172.17.0.2', 9090)
    
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host,port))
    
    message = input("-> ")
    while message !='q':
        s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server)
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("Received from server: " + data)
        message = input("-> ")
    s.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Main()
```

PS: This code works, don't think the python code is the problem here (code taken from an example from the big web). My suspect is the port expose/publish during the docker run, perhaps something I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Where do those two IP addresses come from?  I'd expect, if the server is running in a container, that you'd need to connect to `localhost` and the first published `docker run -p` port number.  You also may explicitly need to tell Docker it's UDP, `-p 9090:9090/udp`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The IP address: 172.17.0.2 belongs to the Linux container-server and on the client-side (windows) : 172.31.16.1 (WSL). sry I gave the wrong ip on my post above (192.168.1.6) it was the local ipv4 add. But still the same response. 

I also ran -p 9090:9090/udp, and again got the same response: "OSError: [WinError 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network"

Comment: ... in addition, I also tried with localhost as server add (should not make any difference?)
   as a note then the line which I get the WinError is when I call "s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server)"...which also makes sense I think

Comment: The usual rules here should apply: the server needs to bind to 0.0.0.0 (or discover the container-private IP, but binding to "everywhere" is easier); you need a `docker run -p` option to publish the port (second port number matches listening port); and from the host, you call `localhost` with the (first) published port.  It may not be `localhost` if you're using a VM-based Docker implementation (Docker Toolbox, Minikube, ...).

Comment: It being UDP, there's also a question of which direction is failing: is the server receiving the request and failing to send the reply, or is the request just not getting there?

Comment: it is UDP yes, the problem here is that the request is not received at the server. The server can send and the data is received at the client, but not the other way around.  I am running "docker run -p 9090:9090/udp". Have also tried to use a different binding port such that the host listen to 9000 and the container on 9090 eg: 9000:9090, still no connection from container to server :(